# Batch copy certain files with wildcard folders

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have limited skills/knowledge of bat files. Basically, I have used them to tidy up a folder for certain file types or to back up files to a dropbox folder.

I now would like to use them to find a file in a certain folder path and copy it to a local drive mirroring the folder path... The folder path has 50 folders and the are over 1000 subfolders.
A couple of examples of the network location:
`Reports\ASD01\ASD01_01
Reports\ASD01\ASD01_02
Reports\ASD01\ASD01_03
Reports\DVC05\DVC05_01
Reports\DVC05\DVC05_12
Reports\DVC05\DVC05_13
Reports\DVC06\DVC06_01`

Each folder contains several files. I am interested in copying a pdf and a CSV from the subfolder to a mirrored folder on my local drive.

I have had a google and XCOPY can't copy folders as wild cards
`Reports\*\*\*.pdf`

I would run the bat periodically to update any new files.
I can't copy the entire contents of subfolder as they would be too large.

I hope I have given enough info and appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Are you asking for all .pdf and .csv files found under `reports` to be copied into you nominated directory?

Comment: I want all the folders that contain PDFs and CSVs to be copied. with the directory mirrored also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to recreatethe folder structure at the destination, then Robocopy is your call.

```
 Robocopy "C:\Source\Reports"  "C:\Destination\Reports" *.pdf /S /DCopy:T /NP /MT:64 /R:2 /W:2 /B
```

The above will copy all PDF files from the Source to the destination and put them in the same subfolders.

You can use the above As-Is in a cmd script, or paste it into the CLI.

If you don't want thefolder structure, than a `For` loop is your pal.

However you have tochangeit slightly depending on if you want to use it in the CLI or in aCMD Script

### CLI

```
@For /F "Tokens=*" %A IN ('
  WHERE /R "C:\Source\Reports" /F "*.pdf"
') DO @(
  IF  NOT EXIST "C:\Destination\%~nxa" @(
    Copy /B /Y /F "%~fA" "C:\Destination\%~nxa"
  )  ELSE @(
     ECHO."C:\Destination\%~nxa" Already Exists, NOT Copying  "%~fA" due to conflict!
  )
)
```

### CopyReplace.cmd

```
@(
  ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET "_Src=C:\Source\Reports"
  SET "_Dst=C:\Destination"
  SET "_FileGlob=*.pdf"
)

For /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
  WHERE /R "%_Src%" /F "%_FileGlob%"
') DO (
  IF  NOT EXIST "%_Dst%\%%~nxa" (
    Copy /B /Y /F "%%~fA" "%_Dst%\%%~nxa"
  )  ELSE (
     ECHO."%_Dst%\%%~nxa" Already Exists, NOT Copying  "%%~fA" due to conflict!
  )
)
```

Comment: I can give this a go tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Is there a way to run it without _run as administrator_ privileges? I think some of my colleagues won't have admin rights.

Comment: So long as source and destination don't require admin priviledges you shouldbe able to read and copy between rhem